# Prevent user from entering UITabBarController with login

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a login view which leads to a `UITabBarController` with four tabs.
What I want is when the password is empty or wrong the user is prompted to stay in the same view (the login view) and not the tab bar controller. In other words I want to be able to view the tab bar if the password is OK (non-empty and correct). Is it possible to keep showing the login view until the provided password is correct? Any ideas?

Comment: Please give more information, are you using storyboard or instatiating everything programatically?

Comment: I am using a storyboard.

Comment: Is your login button connected directly to a storyboard segue or you are calling the segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier`?

Comment: Do you start on another `UIViewController` or are you already on the `UITabBarController`? @araog why does knowing whether they are using storyboard or not matter as this would still have to happen in code and not on storyboard as there are significant validation check that would need to be done around password that would say we need to do this in code.

Comment: @Popeye it really matters, because if he has a button connected directly to a storbyboard segue, then the `UITabBarController` is being called unconditionally, if not, he can add an if and control the call to a segue.

Comment: I start with a UIViewController which is the login screen and then I have added an event to save user input when the login button is clicked and then move into the tab bar.

Comment: @ararog there is significant about of validation that will have to be done against checking whether the user has entered a correct password or not that would mean it would have to be in code. So there is a significant about of information to base your answer on a good assumption which here wouldn't affect the OP if he was using storyboard or not. So need to know whether the OP is using storyboards or not isn't really needed.

Comment: @user1845360 can you edit your question and add the code which is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to disable your tabbar on some time.

If you use `UITabBarController` you can use

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    return NO; 
}
```

or you can disable `userInteractionEnabled`

```
myTabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

You can also add some subview to your `UITabBarController` for example to fade out your tabbar

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
view.alpha = 0.3f;
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:view];
[view release];
```

Comment: How do you get a reference to UITabBarController ?

Comment: If you write code in UIViewController it has property self.tabBarController

Comment: I set userInteractionEnabled but still show the tab bar as before.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled doesn't hide, it make it unselectable, if you want to hide it set tabbar.hidden = YES;

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a modal view controller.  If you have an existing login controller, present it:

```
[someViewController presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

This will position the `loginController` over all other controllers.  When the user has typed the correct password (and only then!) you should dismiss it:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want the `loginController` to have a title bar, remember to wrap it in a `UINavigationController` and present the nav controller instead.

Comment: Whenever I try to dismiss the login view I get: Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <loginViewController:> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to ensure that the code is only being called once?  Are you dismissing in some code that is called as a result of the presentation itself (i.e., `viewDidAppear:`)?

Answer (score 0):

YourAppDelegate.m:

```
@interface YourAppDelegate()
@property( nonatomic, retain ) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property( nonatomic, retain ) UIViewController *loginViewController;
- (void)allocateAndShowLoginViewController;
- (void)allocateAndShowMenuController;
@end
@implementation YourAppDelegate
@synthesize tabBarController;
@synthesize loginViewController;
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];           
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self allocateAndShowLoginViewController];       
    return YES;
}

- (void)allocateAndShowLoginViewController{
     // Show Login View Controller (for example:)
     // My Sample login view controller uses delegate to report when user has been logged in
     self.loginViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
     self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
}  

- (void)allocateAndShowTabBarController{
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];

    UINavigationController      *viewController1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease];

    UINavigationController      *viewController2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}


#pragma mark - loginViewControllerDelegate
- (void)loginViewControllerDidLogin:(PSLoginViewController*)controller{
    [self allocateAndShowMenuController];
}
```

Something like that